# Retrieve bitcoin

Tags: transaction-fees

I recently paid a website with Bitcoin, they requested a certain amount which I sent to them however due to the network fees the amount didn't match the amount requested as a result it wasn't credited to them. Is there a way to retrieve the balance?

Answer (score 3):

If you sent a transaction to the website's bitcoin address and the transaction was confirmed, then you will need to contact the website to have your bitcoin refunded. Bitcoin transactions are not reversible once confirmed in the blockchain, only the person that controls the receiving address can move those coins now.